# export list of object to xml file in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I try to export a list of object(type of "Doctor") to an xml file in c#.
It compiles and runs, but the file I get isn't correct. Can someone please can tell me what I did incorrect?

---

the code is:

```
  public static void exportAsXml(string fileName, List<Entity> ListOfEntity)
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fileName + ".xml");
        StreamWriter sw = file.AppendText();
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer writer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Doctor));
        foreach (Entity e in ListOfEntity)
        {
            writer.Serialize(sw,e as Doctor);
        }
        sw.Close();
    }
```

the xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Doctor xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ID>87587579</ID>
    <FirstName>Dan</FirstName>
    <LastName>Adi</LastName>
    <Gender>male</Gender>
    <Salary>15000</Salary>
</Doctor><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Doctor xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ID>302342246</ID>
    <FirstName>Lital</FirstName>
    <LastName>Gal</LastName>
    <Gender>female</Gender>
    <Salary>25600</Salary>
</Doctor><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Doctor xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ID>205992457</ID>
    <FirstName>Yaron</FirstName>
    <LastName>Mor</LastName>
    <Gender>male</Gender>
    <Salary>10000</Salary>
</Doctor>
```

---

Thanks!

Comment: why isn't it correct?

Comment: Stuff you have written below is not an xml. Where did you get it? Tried to open in browser?

Comment: when I open in browser I got this :
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the resulting xml violates 2 core rules.

1. Xml file should have only one `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">` declaration
2. All your xml should be enclosed inside one root file.

In other words, in loop you generate a separate, fully-fledged xml file for each item.

Try this

```
var writer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Doctor>));
writer.Serialize(sw, ListOfEntity);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are corrupting the xml file by serializing the doctor objects and saving it to the same file using `file.AppendText();`, generating corrupted xml with multiple `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` declarations as consequence.

You should serialize the `List<Doctor>` instead of serializing each doctor alone and modifying the xml file by appending text.

If you want to modify a serialized object saved inside a file, you need to deserialize the file into an object, modify it and then replace the file with the new serialized object. you cannot simply append it.